# Passing params to another Bash file, with spaces

Tags: bash, shell

I want to pass several parameters from one Bash file to another, the problem is, it seems to ignore my quote marks, I dont want to pass it with `$@`.

Here is my current setup:

`agent.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

KEY='INSERT_KEY_HERE';

RESP='command start Test "srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map gm_construct"'

./CMD.sh ${KEY} ${RESP}
```

Actually the `RESP` is coming from a CURL but that gives me the same result.

`CMD.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1;
echo $2;
echo $3;
echo $4;
echo $5;
```

And guess, `$5` gives me:

```
"srcds_run
```

instead of

```
srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map gm_construct
```

what I actually wanted.

So when using `$*` it gives me all parameters, fine but I want them splitted, same as using `$@`, I do overwrite the parameters at the angent.sh script but that turns all parameters into `$2` and I want them splitted...

So any solution to pass Parameters with Spaces without issues?

Comment: BashFAQ #50 -- at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- is relevant to this issue.

Comment: ...short form: You can't avoid `"$@"` or some moral equivalent to it while trying to pass multiple arguments as a unit on argv unless you do something ugly such as (ab)using `eval`, or restrict the space of possible arguments, or require decoding. The only character that isn't possible inside a command-line argument is the same as the only character that isn't possible inside a string; in both cases, it's NUL. This means there's no natural delimiter available to allow literal arrays to be passed on the command line except with one argument for each element.

Comment: Did you try using double quotes around your parameters passed during your ./CMD.sh "${KEY}" "${RESP}" ?

Comment: @narendra, that puts the whole thing in `$2`, but doesn't give the OP a way to *run* it without using `eval`. What they **should** do is follow the caller-side practices suggested by @gniourf_gniourf, then use `shift` to take `KEY` off of `$1`, so that `"$@"` will then refer only to the literal argument list which they're currently trying to pass as `$2`.

Comment: @Neoon Can you extend the question to not elide details about how you're using curl? Also, who controls the file format? (If you wanted to have a file you could download with curl with an arbitrary command line in it, the best choice of format would be a NUL-delimited stream).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you have to use an array (and more quotes):

```
#!/bin/bash

key='INSERT_KEY_HERE'

resp=( command start Test "srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map gm_construct" )

./CMD.sh "$key" "${resp[@]}"
```

Note that I used lowercase variable names (which is good practice!).

Comment: I'd suggest expanding this to demonstrate how to *use* such an argument list (ie. use of `shift` to make `"$@"` refer only to the contents they're presently trying to pass only as `$2`).

Comment: ...I mean, the OP *thinks* they want to pass everything as `$2`, and the code here -- while following best-practices -- isn't doing that, so the answer should be expanded to explain how and why they should use this in place of the thing they think they want.

Comment: Well, thanks but you should mention that thats an array.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: in fact I'm not quite sure what you mean `:D` OP really uses all 5 parameters in their script, and expects `$5` to expand to `srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map gm_construct`, which will. Is there something I'm missing? (also, I'm suspecting that this answer is not enough for OP, since they mention that this `resp` thing comes from `curl`… so I'm expecting we'll need a `read` too to fully answer the question).

Comment: @Neoon: it is an array, and I mentioned it! is there something wrong with that?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Well When I tried to use it like that since my stuff is in a variable get passed by curl: RESP=$(curl -s -d "TOKEN=${KEY}" https://example.net/API.php); and resp=( $RESP ) dosent work so I tried to convert RESP into an array and pass that but that dosent work either.. Any idea?

Comment: @Neoon, as widespread of an idiom as it is, `resp=( $RESP )` isn't the right way to populate an array -- think about what happens if one of the tokens in your string is `*`; you don't want the array to have an entry for every file in the current directory.

Comment: @Neoon, ...and, even more to the point, `resp=( $RESP )` only goes through string-splitting and glob-expansion parsing stages, *not* quote removal. (This is the same problem that BashFAQ #50, to which I linked previously, discusses). Since quotes aren't parsed, your things which are meant to be held together by quotes aren't.

Comment: @Neoon: if you're sure that the output of `curl` is going to be `command start Test "srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map gm_construct"'` you can directly use: `read -r command start test rest < <(curl -s -d "TOKEN=${KEY}" example.net/API.php)`. Then the variables `command`, `start` and `test` will contain the first 3 words, and the `rest` variable will contain the rest (with the double quotes included—you can easily get rid of the double quotes later on).

Comment: Thanks bro, finally its working. Sure I will fiter these commands later just for testing now.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the evil-and-wrong approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

key='INSERT_KEY_HERE'
resp='command start Test "srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map gm_construct"'
eval './cmd "$key" '"$resp" # HUGE SECURITY HOLE DO NOT DO THIS
```

The reason this is evil and wrong is that it trusts the contents of `$resp` to actually be something you can safely execute. Think about what happens if it contains `"$(rm -rf $HOME)"` somewhere -- that would be Very, Very Bad.

---

Now, if you want to form a file that can be *safely* parsed into a list when retrieved over curl, that would look like this:

```
printf '%s\0' command start Test \
  "srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map gm_construct" \
  >cmds.nsv
```

...and then you could read that out from curl and leverage it like so:

```
cmds=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' element; do
  cmds+=( "$element" )
done < <(curl http://path.to/cmds.nsv)

./cmd "$key" "${cmds[@]}"
```